# Mapbox querySourceFeatures return empty result for VectorSource in Android

Tags: vector, geojson, mapbox-android

I've used Android Mapbox SDK to publish a custom vector layer using GeoServer. The layer is shown on the map perfectly but using *querySourceFeatures()* methods as follows return empty result for the features of this vector layer.

```
VectorSource vs = (VectorSource) style.getSources().get(2);
List<Feature> features = vs.querySourceFeatures( new String[]{"lez"} , Expression.literal(true));
```

I've used a GeoJSON layer to use the overloaded version of this method for GeoJsonSource as follows which returns the features of the layer nicely.

```
GeoJsonSource geojson_source = (GeoJsonSource) style.getSources().get(5);
List<Feature> features = geojson_source.querySourceFeatures(Expression.literal(true));
```

So what is wrong with getting features from a VectorSource.

Answer (score 0):

Expression may be wrong. I had same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267691/getting-layer-features-with-querysourcefeature). My items have "branch" property and I used this expression: `neq(get("branch"), literal(""))`

Expression means that get items which have not `branch != ""` . I know it isn't healthy method but it works.

```
List<Feature> all_features = source.querySourceFeatures(source_layers, neq(get("branch"), literal("")));
```