# Getting layer features with querySourceFeature

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I'm trying to get all features from Mapbox style layer. I found querySourceFeature() method. However, I cannot get exact source. Here simple code block from Mapbox documentation.

I don't use GeoJsonSource for styling, I mean I dont add any GeoJsonSouce. So, "source" variable returns "null" and I did not understand what should come instead of GeoJsonSource and "population-source".

```
GeoJsonSource source = style.getSourceAs("population-source");
List<Feature> features = source.querySourceFeatures(Expression.get("population"));
```

To sum up, I want to get all features in one layer from Mapbox style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get style layer as source, we should use `VectorSource()`.

`VectorSource source = style.getSourceAs("composite");`

"composite" is layer' source variable in "style.json".

For `querySourceFeatures()`, we should give `layerSource(String[])` and `Expression`.

`List<Feature> all_features = source.querySourceFeatures(source_layers,Expression);`

"source_layers" is layer' source-layer variable in "style.json".